# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://blaablaaa.co" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: domexception

I am getting the above message. blaablaa isn't the actual site address obviously. I have tried the work around using jsfiddle but I am still getting the same message.

```
 <script>

   var frame = document.getElementById('test'); 
   frame.contentWindow.postMessage("HELLO", '*'); 
</script>
<iframe id="test" src="https://blaablaa.co/">
    <script>
       window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { 

       // IMPORTANT: Check the origin of the data! 
      if (~event.origin.indexOf('https://jsfiddle.net')) { 
         // The data has been sent from your site 

         // The data sent with postMessage is stored in event.data 
         console.log(event.data); 
     } else { 
         // The data hasn't been sent from your site! 
        // Be careful! Do not use it. 
         return; 
    } 
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am presuming yes but I don't know what. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AHH

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

```
   // IMPORTANT: Check the origin of the data! 
  if (~event.origin.indexOf('https://jsfiddle.net')) { 
     // The data has been sent from your site 

     // The data sent with postMessage is stored in event.data 
     console.log(event.data); 
 } else { 
     // The data hasn't been sent from your site! 
    // Be careful! Do not use it. 
     return; 
}
```

});

should be part of the src called by the iframe not within  I think. I wasn't sure but I have now found another example